# lost connection with mail.myserver.com [xx.xx.xx.xx] while sending end of data

Tags: exchange, email-server

some senders report errors with my server:

Error log:

Action: failed
Status: 4.4.2
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; lost connection with
    mail.myserver.com [xx.xx.xx.xx]] while sending end of data -- message
    may be sent more than once

My mail server is a Exchange 2010 with Forefront TMG 2010

I don´t know the reason, with gmail work fine